# how to show the print preview category?

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, preview, cview

Well I am working with visual studio 2015  on an mfc project.
I have enabled the office like ribbon in the project creation wizard.
I am inheriting from CView for my view class to get printing support as documentation suggests.
I have also overrided OnDraw too.
Now I want to get a print preview of the document with the print preview options on the ribbon. 
I don't know where to start or how to act.
Any suggestions, propositions or examples ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do it again for print preview window.

When you start a new "MFC application" for MDI and "Ribbon control", the application it self provides a print preview option.

Once you create a new application, Run the application.

The application runs and a windows opens.

Select the options as shown in below images.

You will get "print preview" option.

Search in the source code for "print view" to understand how it is implemented.[image]

[image]

Comment: Right I have found how to display the print preview and the print preview category on the ribbon. Thanks.